Capturing console and not affecting the log line
I am working on a class that will be used for console logging, but with every call a new object will be added to the console history array. I created a class ConsoleLogger

    export class ConsoleLogger {
      private static instance: ConsoleLogger | null = null;

      private logs: LogEntry[] = [];
      private maxLogs = 50;

      public static getInstance(): ConsoleLogger {
        if (this.instance === null) {
          this.instance = new ConsoleLogger();
        }
        return this.instance;
      }

      private addLog(type: LogType, message: string): void {
        if (this.logs.length >= this.maxLogs) {
          this.logs.shift();
        }
        this.logs.push({ type, message, timestamp: new Date() });
      }


      public log = (function () {
        return Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console);
      })();

 public error = (function () {
    return Function.prototype.bind.call(console.error, console);
  })();
}


I can use it in .vue and .ts files, with e.g.
ConsoleLogger.getInstance().log('console msg'); and the line information is refering correctly, to my .ts file/.vue file. I am not sure how can I connect addLog line to each of these methods, as I cannot refer to this.addLog in this exact log function, and if I try to change the log method that I will make this.addLog available, then I am losing the proper line information as it starts refering to the line in my consoleLogger.ts.
How can I not lose the line information and also use my addLog method properly?
Edit:
I tried to use binding,
public log = function (...args: any[]) {
    this.addLog("log", args.join(" "));
    return Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console);
}.bind(this)();

But the args argument still being empty, even if I use consoleLogger.log("test test"), there is no "test test" saved.

Use apply or bind to preserve the original console.log/console.error behavior.

I tried with binding this, but my args are empty which results in empty messages in console history array.

There are much less use cases for bind and bind.call since ES6, and they are undesirable in TS because they are type unsafe. It's not necessary to use call here too because this is solved with spread syntax:
public log(...args: any[]) {
     this.addLog("log", args.join(" "));
     console.log(...args);
}
     

